# IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds error while downloading data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime, quandl

I am running a code to download data and saving them in local drive. However, I am getting above mentioned error message. Please note initially I have converted date in a different format and while saving them I get this error message.

Can you please help me with this error?

'''

import quandl
import os
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import glob

if **name** == "**main**":

```
'Creating bucket to store missing data file.'
data_missing = []
New_date = []

'Defining a path to save CSV files after downloading and also deleting all csv file at one go.'
extension = 'csv'
path = "F:/Tradepoint/MyMkt/"
if not os.path.exists(path):
       os.mkdir(path)
os.chdir(path)
csv_count = [forma for forma in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
for csv_coun in range(len(csv_count)):
    os.remove(r"F:/Tradepoint/MyMkt/" + csv_count[csv_coun][0:])

'Setting up quandl configuration, reading ticker list, setting up date for which data is going to get downloaded'
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'Hba3CzgNnEa2LMxR14FA'
end_date = dt.date.today()
diff_year = dt.timedelta(days=3650)
start_date = end_date - diff_year
stock_list = pd.read_csv(r"F:\Abhay_New\Abhay\Python\Project\SHARADAR_SF1.csv")

'Looping through quandl website to download data and renaming them as per requirement.'
for stock_lis in range(len(stock_list)):
    data = quandl.get_table('SHARADAR/SEP', date={'gte':start_date, 'lte':end_date}, ticker=stock_list.iloc[stock_lis])
    sort_by_date = data.sort_values('date')
    for sort_by_dat in range(len(sort_by_date['date'])):
        Date = dt.date.strftime(sort_by_date['date'][sort_by_dat],'%d-%m-%Y')
        New_date.append(Date)
    if len(data)>1:
        Date = pd.Series(New_date).rename('Date').astype(str)
        OPEN = sort_by_date['open']
        HIGH = sort_by_date['high']
        LOW =  sort_by_date['low']
        CLOSE = sort_by_date['close']
        VOLUME = sort_by_date['volume']
        final_data = pd.concat([Date,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,VOLUME],axis=1)
        stk = stock_list.iloc[sort_by_dat][0]
        final_data.to_csv(str(path + stk + '.csv'), sep=',', index = False, header = False)
    else:
        data_missing.append(stock_list.iloc[sort_by_dat])
```

print(data_missing)

'''

Thanks,
Abhay Dodiya

Comment: Can you include the full stack trace for the error?

Comment: @user2314737 Trace added to above question. Can you please look into it. Thanks

Comment: could you show a sample from `stock_list`? Can you reproduce the error, when you remove almost all the stuff here? I mean ```for i in range(stock_list): stock_list.iloc[0][1]``` should fail already. Instead of the whole for loop.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 In stock_list currently i am having only one option "A" which is name of stock. I wanted to try first with one ticker so i did that way. However, I am still getting an error message. Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: Again, please show some data. Additionally, you are using some kind of chained indexing during accessing `.iloc`. I think this might not be doing what you think it should do. But again, need data to verify

Answer (score 0):

The index of both for loops is `i`. This causes potentially unintended behavior:

```
for i in range(2):
     for i in range(3,11):
         pass
     print(i)
```

gives

```
10
10
```

So even after exiting the second loop, the last value from `i` is there. Rename the counting variable in that loop and your issue should be gone.
In your case you probably have more dates than stocks, and thus observe the error message you have.

Comment: I tried renaming it but still giving me same error message. Please see above revised code.

Comment: Stack trace is missing. Please add it. Additionally provide data please.  All we can do under these circumstances is guessing